# Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzee;

Tags: android, dex

hi i have error on my android studio

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzee;
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
> >     java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with
> >     arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --output

My  build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.brommko.android.promophotography"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 14
        versionName "3.4"
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "c0fbadc6-4013-4613-b00b-566eab144d3c",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "4122760152"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4"
    compile 'com.github.quentin7b:android-location-tracker:3.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: go for this link https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: Do you have anything in your `libs/` directory? If yes, try to switch from plain JARs to artifacts (the way the rest of your `compile` lines are), and that may help clear up this problem. If `libs/` is empty, you can comment out the `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` line (as you are not using it), though this will not help address your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you've mixed version of dependencies. The problem is because **OneSignal** automatically adds the following dependencies:

```
com.google.android.gms - Version 11.2.+
com.android.support - Version 26.1.+
```

So, you need to change your support, Firebase, and google play service dependencies version. It will be like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    // Don't use +, use exact dependency version.
    //compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.5, 3.99.99]'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.1'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.1"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.2.1'

    compile 'com.github.quentin7b:android-location-tracker:3.2'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
}
```

Read more at [Troubleshooting Android](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-android)